# make async method await an event with Dart

Tags: events, async-await, dart

I want to test if a method fires an event. If the event was fired synchronously the test method would look something like this:

```
stringBindable_input_firesEvent() {
  iBindable str = BindableFactory.fromType(Types.String_);
  bool wasTriggered = false;
  str.onChangeForGui.listen((v) {
    wasTriggered = true;
  });
  str.input("test"); //this triggers the event
  expect(wasTriggered, isTrue);
}
```

Since the event is fired `async` I need to `await` it to be fired. 
How would I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to test a single event, you can use `expectAsync1`

```
  str.onChangeForGui.listen(expectAsync1((v) {
    wasTriggered = true;
  }));
```

The test will fail if `expectAsync1` wasn't called before the test times out.

For more complex scenarios I'd use one of the [Stream Matchers](https://github.com/dart-lang/test#stream-matchers)

```
expect(str.onChangeForGui, emitsInOrder([(e) => e != null]));
```

If you need to invoke code to cause the events to emit, you could use

```
final eventsFired = expectLater(str.onChangeForGui, emitsInOrder([(e) => e != null]));
// fire events
return eventsFired; // make the test work for this check
```